Finding the Impulse Response of an LTI System

Source: Signals and Systems, Oppenheim, et al., page 152, 2nd edition.$$\\$$
Here is what I've figured:
$$x'(t) = 2(-3e^{-3t}u(t-1)+e^{-3t}u'(t-1))\\
=-3x(t)+e^{-3t}\delta(t-1)
$$
Now, since this is a linear, time-invariant system, inputting the above into the system gives $$-3y(t)+S(e^{-3t} \delta(t-1))$$
If I could isolate the unit sample function (ex. if e^-3t was a scalar) then I can get the impulse response pretty easily.  Not sure where to go now.

RD Healthcare - Hi, It seems you've copied the question image from somewhere. To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each copied / adapted item. If the original source is online & public, please [edit] the question & add the webpage/PDF/etc. name & its link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + its URL). If the source is offline (e.g. printed book / private intranet) then [edit] the question & add full source details e.g. title, author, page, publisher, edition. TY

One other point: FYI, although questions about EE LTI systems are on-topic here, the question doesn't show any EE details. If this is an abstract LTI question, it may be better received elsewhere on SE e.g. Math.SE or DSP.SE, although some site members have answered abstract LTI questions here in the past. (However, don't ask the same question on multiple SE sites - pick one site to ask on and stick with it.) || For future reference, please see the site [tour] & [help]. Our on-topic subject list is here. TY

Thanks.  I’ll edit this when I get home.

After some calculations, I get the transfer function which is absurd.. In the photo my procedure:

